# LINQ GroupBy by Anonymous Object Not actually grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering why my LINQ GroupBy statement isn't actually grouping my set of objects correctly. I still get all the objects I started out with even though they share the same Key.

here is the code that I have tried:

```
var snapshot = snapshotService.GetSnapshot(siids, warehouseId)
   .GroupBy(a => new
   {
      a.SIId,
      a.WarehouseId,
      a.Treatment,
      a.UnitOfMeasure
   })
   .Select(a => new Snapshot
   {
      SIId = a.Key.SIId,
      WarehouseId = a.Key.WarehouseId,
      Treatment = a.Key.Treatment,
      UnitOfMeasure = a.Key.UnitOfMeasure,
      TotalAmount = a.Sum(sum => sum.TotalAmount),
      Available = a.Sum(sum => sum.Available),
      Unavailable = a.Sum(sum => sum.Unavailable)
   }).ToList();
```

The Key is SIId, WarehouseId, Treatment, and UnitOfMeasure. I would like one return set for every key combination. I instead am getting multiple return sets for every key combination and it is so annoying! There are different values for TotalAmount, Available, and Unavailable as well. It's almost as if the GroupBy statement is getting completely annoyed.

For example: If I have an objects

```
{SIId = 1, WareHouseId = 1, Treatment = 1, UnitOfMeasure = 1,
  TotalAmount = 1, Available = 1, Unavailable = 1}
{SIId = 1, WareHouseId = 1, Treatment = 1, UnitOfMeasure = 1,
  TotalAmount = 2, Available = 2, Unavailable = 2}
```

I would expect the return to be:

```
{SIId = 1, WareHouseId = 1, Treatment = 1, UnitOfMeasure = 1,
  TotalAmount = 3, Available = 3, Unavailable = 3}
```

However I am getting the composite list

```
{
  {SIId = 1, WareHouseId = 1, Treatment = 1, UnitOfMeasure = 1,
    TotalAmount = 1, Available = 1, Unavailable = 1},
  {SIId = 1, WareHouseId = 1, Treatment = 1, UnitOfMeasure = 1,
    TotalAmount = 2, Available = 2, Unavailable = 2}
}.
```

What gives?

Comment: How are you viewing these results? If you are looking in the debugger you might not actually see grouped data as it will just give you the results in groups when you enumerate them.

Comment: Postman returns

Comment: @NICOBHHCCoder postman is not how you debug things.

Comment: I wasn't debugging...

Comment: You are getting a http response so your group are the element objects and not the text values.  Use : a.SIId.Text,a.WarehouseId.Text, a.Treatment.Text, a.UnitOfMeasure.Text

Comment: What happens in `snapshotService.GetSnapshot`? What is the base data source of the data?

Comment: @NICOBHHCCoder
There is nothing wrong with the code i guess . i seems that you are getting this output from some other peace of code 
See this its working very fine here  https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3WDL2

Answer (score 0):

its not a full answer, but i adjusted your code to execute to show there is nothing wrong with code and it return what was expected

```
void Main()
{
    var snapshot = ((List<Snapshot>)snapshotService.GetSnapshot())
   .GroupBy(a => new
   {
       a.SIId,
       a.WarehouseId,
       a.Treatment,
       a.UnitOfMeasure
   })
   .Select(a => new Snapshot
       {
           SIId = a.Key.SIId,
           WarehouseId = a.Key.WarehouseId,
           Treatment = a.Key.Treatment,
           UnitOfMeasure = a.Key.UnitOfMeasure,
           TotalAmount = a.Sum(sum => sum.TotalAmount),
           Available = a.Sum(sum => sum.Available),
           Unavailable = a.Sum(sum => sum.Unavailable)
      }).ToList();

      snapshot.Dump();    
}
public class Snapshot
{
    public int SIId { get; set; }
    public int WarehouseId {get;set;}
    public int Treatment { get; set; }
    public int UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public int Unavailable { get; set; }
}

public static class snapshotService
{
    public static object GetSnapshot()
    {
        string x = "[{\"SIId\":1,\"WareHouseId\":1,\"Treatment\":1,\"UnitOfMeasure\":1,\"TotalAmount\":1,\"Available\":1,\"Unavailable\":1},{\"SIId\":1,\"WareHouseId\":1,\"Treatment\":1,\"UnitOfMeasure\":1,\"TotalAmount\":2,\"Available\":2,\"Unavailable\" :2}]";
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Snapshot>>(x);
    }
}
```

the result came back:
[image]